# Stuck on traversing a html dom on a page

Tags: php, html, dom, traversal

Ok. I'm stuck once again and it seems that internet just ran out of traversing a dom with HTML DOM tutorials. I have this page (http://www.nasdaqomxbaltic.com/market/?pg=news&news_id=250910) and what I'm trying to do is to get the text `The statement of shareholders for shares sale and for shares purchase attached.` and the attached files into a variables. I'm trying to do it the most efficient way so I'm not using simple_html_dom. I wouldn't use xpath if i had choice or if it would be faster, but I'm not sure:)

EDIT: Tried Phil's code. Can't seem to figure out why it still doesn't work.

```
   <?
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.nasdaqomxbaltic.com/market/?pg=news&news_id=250910");

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$paragraph = $xpath->query('//table[@id="previewTable"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/p');//tried removing tbody, doesn't fix, why is it there?
if ($paragraph->length == 1) {//what is this?
     $sentence = $paragraph->nodeValue;
    print_r($sentence);//doesnt work (blank)
}
$links = $xpath->query('//table[@id="previewTable"]//td[@class="tdAttachment"]//a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $linkName = $link->nodeValue;
    $linkUrl = $link->getAttribute('href');
echo $linkName;
echo $linkUrl;//works
}
?>
```

Comment: nope - it doesn't work like that

Comment: You don't need `file_get_contents()`, just use `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how fixed that markup is.

Assuming the structure is fairly static, to retrieve the sentence, try

```
$paragraphs = $xpath->query('//table[@id="previewTable"]/tr[2]/td/p');
if ($paragraphs->length > 0) { // check to make sure we got at least one node
    $sentence = $paragraphs->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Retrieving the links is slightly more complex

```
$links = $xpath->query('//table[@id="previewTable"]//td[@class="tdAttachment"]//a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $linkName = $link->nodeValue;
    $linkUrl = $link->getAttribute('href');

    // do something with these values
}
```

Comment: @Josh My bad, I forgot to get the first paragraph item. Also removed `tbody`, shouldn't use a DOM inspector to read source code. Updated my answer

Comment: Great! This works perfectly. Is there a html dom method for getting for example the source of the //table[@id="previewTable"] tag? (i mean with all the tags except this table tag).

Comment: @Josh Google "php dom innerhtml"